# Javascript iPad Return Key event?

Tags: javascript

On a JavaScript page, I pop up an alert if the user hits the enter key by using

```
if(evt.keyCode == 13){
    alert("Return Key Pressed");
}
```

but the event does not fire when I hit the return key on the iPad. How do I catch the event?

Comment: Check if the target element is focused.

Comment: How to check and if not focused, how do I set it focused? Note that the element I am using is a textbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iPad keyboard *does* fire the `keypress` event with a key code of 13 if you press return.  This sounds like you've got something else going awry

Here's a quick jsfiddle to verify with: http://jsfiddle.net/359wG/

Answer (score 0):

According to https://api.jquery.com/keypress/

> The keypress event is sent to an element when the browser registers
>   keyboard input. This is similar to the keydown event, except that
>   modifier and non-printing keys such as Shift, Esc, and delete trigger
>   keydown events but not keypress events. Other differences between the
>   two events may arise depending on platform and browser.
>
> A keypress event handler can be attached to any element, but the event
>   is only sent to the element that has the focus. Focusable elements can
>   vary between browsers, but form controls can always get focus so are
>   reasonable candidates for this event type.

I moved my return-key listener to an anchor tag, which on IPad is treated as a 'focusable element' similar to form controls.