# JavaScript Shows Same KeyCode

Tags: javascript, ios

In my ios application,I want to detect return key.So i used this javaScript.

```
function onKeyPress(e)
{
   alert(e.keyCode);
   if (e.keyCode == 13 ) {
     window.location.href = "newline://buttonClicked";
   }
}
```

When I use internal keyboard I can get correct key code,but if I use external keyboard it always gives `0` value.

How can I detect correct key code from external keyboard?

Comment: You can reference this site, http://notes.ericjiang.com/posts/333

Comment: I'd suggest checking `e.which` to see if it has the desired value.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509253/javascript-ipad-return-key-event) suggests that `e.keyCode` works fine, but you have to make sure you manually apply focus to a field before the events will be available.  I don't have an iPad to test, just reporting results from Google searches.

Comment: Another [possibly relevant post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588899/how-can-i-add-a-javascript-listener-to-capture-input-from-bluetooth-barcode-scan) about iso not firing keyboard events except on elements inside a form after they've been explicitly given focus which cannot be done via javascript and has to be done by the user directly.

Answer (score 1):

Please check with

```
function onKeyPress(e)
{
   alert(e.which);

}
```

Comment: Do you know this works on ios with external keyboard?  Or is this just a guess?  If it's just a wild guess, it has already been suggested via comment which is what is appropriate for speculative guesses that are simple.