# window.addEventListener('keyup') in ios iPad

Tags: javascript, ios

I created a web app to read barcode with a bar code scanner.

I have the next code:

```
window.addEventListener('keyup', this.validateCode);

function validateCode(e){

    // If is enter
    if(e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        search();
    }
    else
    {
        // Add the value to the code
        code += e.key;
    }
}
```

It works in android and in desktop very well, but in iOs it always return me 'undefined' value or 0, I'm not sure if iOs or the iPad do not recognize window listener.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MattClark that's no good because `this.validateCode(e)` doesn't return a function.

Comment: Try using 'keypress' instead of 'keyup' as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509253/javascript-ipad-return-key-event)

Comment: I changed keyup to keypress and that solve my temporal problem, but when I created the home screen app the iPad doesn't recognize the keypress, also I print the alert with the keycode alert(e.keyCode);